# Error in implementing a custom view in android:

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I'm trying to implement a custom View in my application. I went over this page: 
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

and I have created the following:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/left_menu_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="gone" >

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/left_menu_close_button"
    android:onClick="showLeftMenu" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/left_menu_separator" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_menu_buttons_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_menu_data_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_menu_button_transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" 
            android:onClick="showSelectTab">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left_menu_data_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent_rectangle"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/folder" 
                android:onClick="showSelectTab"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/left_menu_data"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Data"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" 
                android:onClick="showSelectTab"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_menu_separator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_menu_settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" 
            android:onClick="showSettingsPopup">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent_rectangle"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/settings" 
                android:onClick="showSettingsPopup"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white" 
                android:onClick="showSettingsPopup">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_menu_separator" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and those classes:

**AppViewLinearLayout:**

```
package com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AppViewLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

public AppViewLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int layoutResource)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, null);
    addView(view);
}
```

}

and: **LeftSideMenu:**

```
package com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.ui;

import com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class LeftSideMenu extends AppViewLinearLayout
{
private LeftSideMenuClickListener mListener;

public LeftSideMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int layoutResource) 
{
    super(context, attrs, layoutResource);
    findViewById(R.id.left_menu_data).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.dataOnClick(v);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.left_menu_settings).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.settingsOnClick(v);
        }
    });
}

public interface LeftSideMenuClickListener {
    void dataOnClick(View v);

    void settingsOnClick(View v);
}
```

}

Now I try to add it to my main layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginScrActivity" >

<com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.ui.LeftSideMenu
    android:id="@+id/leftSideMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
....
```

and for some reason I receive this in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.emildesign.sgreportmanager/com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.activi
ties.ReportsTableActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line
#10: Error inflating class com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.ui.LeftSideMenu
```

**UPDATE:**

I made the following change, in `LeftSideMenu`:

```
public LeftSideMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs, R.layout.left_menu);
            .....
```

The error was gone, but I still can see my custom layout.

Hirarchy Viewer:

[image]
What am I doing wrong? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this constructor:

```
public LeftSideMenu (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. please see update question. but for some reason I still can't see my custom view.

Comment: try to run hierarchyviewer, what do you see?

Comment: and for your root view, what are the properties Layout>getWidth()/getHeight() ?

Comment: I posted my main layout as well in it the width and height properties are set to match_parent. this custom view is a part of my main view.

Comment: i don't mean android:layout_width / android:layout_height, i mean what you see in hierarchviewer

Comment: I dont have such a good practice with the hierarchyviewer. could you tell me where do I look for it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html, search **Properties View**

Comment: aha! so there is problem with layout phase, or maybe isInEditMode() returns true?

Comment: when would the isInEditMode() return true? when I edit it in the graphical layout editor and in the same time try to run the project on the emulator or a real device?

Comment: at runtime, but what if you delete addView and instead change inflate(layoutResource, this) ?

Comment: stupid me, Thank you for your help. the problem was this line in my custom view: android:visibility="gone" for the first LinearLayout.

Comment: :-) no problem, at least you know a bit more about hierarchyviewer

Comment: Yes, and I better read this google material in the link you gave me to realy understand how to use it : )

Comment: would you mind to look into this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217463/onclicks-in-a-custom-view-are-not-responding